# Adding new item to the start of MongoDB database with Express

Tags: database, mongodb, api, express, mongoose

I have a mongoDB database storing a list of items:

```
[{"_id":"0", "a": "b"}, {"_id":"1", "a": "c"}]
```

To add a new item to the database via a POST request, I am using Express router and Mongoose:

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    const newItem = new Item({a: req.body.a})
    newItem.save()
    .then(item => res.json(item))
})
```

After this, the database looks like:

```
[{"_id":"0", a: "b"}, {"_id":"1", a: "c"}, {new item}]
```

Is there any way to instead add the new item to the front, like this?

```
[{new item}, {"_id":"0", "a": "b"}, {"_id":"1", "a": "c"}]
```

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: `newItem.save().then(items => res.json(items))` This is not returning list of item, can you share code of find items.

Comment: @RahulSharma right, that line should actually read `.then(item => res.json(item))` (after the item is added, I return the item that was added in the response). Either way though the item still always gets added to the end of the list by default. Is there a way to add it to the start?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using mongoose

````
Item.find({},(err,data)=>{
   if(err){
     res.send(err);
     console.log(err);
   }
   else{
     res.send(data);
   }
})```
this is the way to fetch all data from collection using mongoose.
````

Comment: Thank you. I am using Mongoose and have no issue with fetching all of the data, I'm wondering if a new item can be added to the beginning of the collection list rather than the end via a POST request.